# CanvasJS and multiple piecharts.

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have to create pie charts for a website. It seems to me that I can't dynamically render pie charts depending on how many I need. At max I have to render 28. So, I'm thinking that I would have to type out

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {
        title:{
            text: "Gaming Consoles Sold in 2012"
        },
        legend: {
            maxWidth: 350,
            itemWidth: 120
        },
        data: [
        {
            type: "pie",
            showInLegend: true,
            legendText: "{indexLabel}",
            dataPoints: [
                { y: 4181563, indexLabel: "PlayStation 3" },
                { y: 2175498, indexLabel: "Wii" },
                { y: 3125844, indexLabel: "Xbox 360" },
                { y: 1176121, indexLabel: "Nintendo DS"},
                { y: 1727161, indexLabel: "PSP" },
                { y: 4303364, indexLabel: "Nintendo 3DS"},
                { y: 1717786, indexLabel: "PS Vita"}
            ]
        }
        ]
    });
    chart.render();
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

this code 28 times. But, sometimes I won't need all 28 pie charts. So I was thinking I could hide the pie charts if they aren't needed. But, the main question is, "**can I dynamically allocate canvasJS pie charts**"? So I only have one main block of code that can create X amount of pie charts.

Comment: A possible thought would be to create two variables at the head of the JS file. One variable would be an array of charts which would be filled up with canvasJS charts. The second variable would be a 2 tuple of data that would fill in the chart. The tuple would be (int, string). Then a simple for loop would be used to populate the array of charts.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. So following my original comment. I hard coded the 2 tuple variable in the data section just to get the basic idea running. So the variable data was not used. But, I followed through with just simply creating an array of charts. With a naming convention of pieContainer+i. Where in my html code. I have 29 div elements with the convention pieContainer+1.

```
var charts = [];
var data = [];

function populatePieCharts(size)
{
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        console.log("FFFF" + i)
        charts[i] = new CanvasJS.Chart("pieContainer" + i,
            {
                title: {
                    text: i
                },
                legend: {
                    maxWidth: 350,
                    itemWidth: 120
                },
                data: [
                    {
                        type:"pie",
                        showInLegend: true,
                        legendText: "{indexLabel}",
                        dataPoints: [
                            { y: 4181563, indexLabel: "PlayStation 3" },
                            { y: 2175498, indexLabel: "Wii" },
                            { y: 3125844, indexLabel: "Xbox 360" },
                            { y: 1176121, indexLabel: "Nintendo DS" }
                        ]
                    }]
            }); 
    }
    renderCharts(size)
}
function renderCharts(chartAmount)
{
    console.log(charts.length);
    for (i2 = 0; i2 < chartAmount; i2++)
    {
        charts[i2].render();
        console.log(i2);
    }
}
```

Which leads me to another step. Instead of hard coding the 29 div elements. I could probably just dynamically create the div elements based on the pie charts needed.